# Using swift style access with rclone and non-classic OCI object storage

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, rclone

Can anyone comment on if it should be possible to use rclone's swift support to access buckets in OCI object storage (new OCI, not classic).

I'm interested in it because S3 compatibility mode is limited to a single designated compartment and I'd like to be able to use rclone with any bucket in my tenancy.

I know that for public buckets there is still a swift style URL. The 3 functional URLs styles seem to be:

- Native: https://objectstorage.{region}.oraclecloud.com/n/{object-storage-namespace}/b/{bucket}/o/{filename}
- Swift: https://swiftobjectstorage.{region}.oraclecloud.com/v1/{object-storage-namespace}/{bucket}/{filename}
- S3: https://{object-storage-namespace}.compat.objectstorage..oraclecloud.com/{bucket}/{filename}

https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Identity/Tasks/managingcredentials.htm talks a little bit about Swift password (Auth Tokens) and you can create one in the console.

But I can't find anything about what the **auth** URL would be for the non-classic version of object storage. And storage_url with a auth_token doesn't seem to work either.

Using -vvvv doesn't show anything more than 401 Unauthorized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm interested in it because S3 compatibility mode is limited to a single designated compartment and I'd like to be able to use rclone with any bucket in my tenancy.

The designated compartment only controls where buckets created via that protocol (S3 or Swift) are placed. The designated compartment does not affect authorization. Authorization is controlled by the relevant IAM policies.

> But I can't find anything about what the auth URL would be for the non-classic version of object storage. And storage_url with a auth_token doesn't seem to work either.

The new/current OCI Object Storage does not support auth URLs. You must use HTTP basic-style auth with Swift on OCI. It does not seem that rclone supports HTTP basic auth with swift directly (it is possible to create the basic auth header yourself and have rclone send it).

All that said, using rclone with s3 is the best approach for OCI Object Storage. Ensure you set the "region" option to the correct region name like "us-phoenix-1" and you should be good.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that the limitation was just about bucket creation and that Swift API access has the same limitation as S3 based access.

Comment: I was able to trick rclone into using Swift with OCI object storage. You can set a junk auth_token value so that rclone doesn't try to talk to a Swift auth server and set a storage_url that includes your HTTP basic auth username and password(token). I documented it on http://blog.osdev.org/oci/2020/10/15/oci-objectstorage-with-rclone.html but you're right, its really easier just to use S3.